# "module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'" running a simple pygame script

Tags: python, pygame

When i run my pygame code, i get the following error:

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:/Users/lanra/Desktop/2018 backups/2018 python/pygame/pygame 2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lanra/Desktop/2018 backups/2018 python/pygame/pygame 2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:/Users/lanra/Desktop/2018 backups/2018 python/pygame\pygame.py", line 3, in <module>
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'
```

My code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("first game")

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

run= True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0))

    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The error says that there's no function named `init` in `pygame`. Have you checked the reference for what `pygame` exists of?

Comment: You called your program `pygame 2.py`, and it seems that you already had another called `pygame.py` in the same directory. That is the one that gets imported. Remove or rename it.

Comment: You must not name your file `pygame.py` or Python will think your file is the pygame library. Just rename it.

Comment: @skrx you could/should've actually VTC, in particular because the OP can univocally accept closure as duplicate.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Sorry my mistake. That answer is for some reason displayed at the bottom of answers list for me, below a deleted answer. It is the most upvoted answer, but not accepted. It *does* look like a duplicate.

Comment: @NeilSlater you have answer sorting set to "active".

Comment: @NeilSlater I may've been mistaken, too: while the answer is the same, in that case, it's impossible to say whether the reason is that or not since there's zero info provided.

Comment: You guys are very smart!!! I did it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a script called `pygame.py` locally to your test script. This is getting imported instead of the library.

The fix is to rename your local `pygame.py` script (which is presumably another version of this one as you are figuring out Pygame) so it does not conflict. In general, avoid naming your project files the same as the libraries that you are using.

You also have other errors in your code (please read the Pygame documentation and examples), but this will be the first fix you need to apply, and it is not specific to Pygame.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("first game")

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

while True:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), win.get_rect())

    pygame.display.update()
```

Note the extra required param to `pygame.draw.rect` and call to `pygame.display.update()`. Also modified the while loop, as once you have called `pygame.quit()` you don't want to call things like `pygame.event.get()` else you will get error messages about no video system.

Comment: Although I agree the initial error is a duplicate, I have shown extra fixes here to OP's code, so will leave the answer up.

Comment: I did it! You are very smart!!!

Comment: @DragonProgram please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: OK I am a newbie of stackoverflow. I have accepted this answer. You guys can see the accept?

Comment: @DragonProgram: Yes. Thank you for accepting the answer, and glad it helped.